# The following code is an attempt to implement the Rule of 3, but Im getting a few errors

Tags: c++

I'm getting 8 errors in this program. Can anyone help?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class Name {
   const char* m_value;

   void allocateAndCopy(const char* value) {
      delete[] m_value;
      m_value = new char[strlen(value) + 1];
      strcpy(m_value, value);
   }

public:
   Name() :m_value(nullptr) {
   };

   Name(const char* value) :m_value(nullptr) {
      allocateAndCopy(value);
   }

   Name(Name& N) {
      *this = N;
   }

   Name operator=(const Name& N) {
      allocateAndCopy(N.m_value);
      return this;
   }

   ~Name() {
      delete[] m_value;
   }

   void display(ostream& os)const {
      os << m_value;
   }

   void read(istream& is) {
      char val[1000];
      getline(is, val);
      allocateAndCopy(val.c_str());
   }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Name& N) {
   N.display(os);
   return os;
}

istream& operator<<(istream& is, Name& N) {
   return N.read(is);
}
```

The errors I'm getting are:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0167   argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "char *"
and more.
```

Comment: Take one error at a time. Don't implement a whole program at once. Do it in small increments. Asking about 8 errors is too broad of a question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Suggestion: when you don't understand the abbreviated error message in the Error List, switch to the Output tab that's beside it and see if the complete error message in the full build output is more useful. Even when it isn't, it's low-glamour plaintext presentation usually pastes into a Stack Overflow question better.

Comment: remove the const from this line: `const char* m_value;`  You are changing `m_value` so it isn't const
`

Comment: You should identify the line that triggers the error. Even better, remove all the functions except the one with the error (making it even easier to see which line has the error). For bonus points, explain why you think the error is wrong (e.g. Do you think the types are something other than what is in the error message? Why do you believe your types are appropriate?)

Answer (score 1):

There are at least four fundamental bugs/problems with the shown code.

```
 strcpy(m_value, value);
```

`m_value` is a `const char *`, a pointer to ***constant characters***. "constant" means that you can't `strcpy()` over them, of course.

Instead of immediately assigning the result of `new []` to `m_value`, and then `strcpy()` into it, the result of `new []` should be stored in a temporary `char *`, then `strcpy()`ed; and then the temporary `char *` can finally be placed into the `m_value`.

```
Name(Name& N) {
```

A proper copy constructor should take a `const` reference as a parameter, this should be `Name(const Name &N)`.

```
Name(Name& N) {
  *this = N;
}
```

This constructor fails to initialize the `m_value` class member. The constructor then calls the overloaded `operator=`. It will, eventually, attempt to delete `m_value`, which was never initialized. This results in undefined behavior, and a likely crash. You will need to fix this bug as well.

```
 Name operator=(const Name& N) {
```

An overloaded `operator=` is expected to return a reference to `this`, not a brand new object. This should return a `Name &`, and actually return `*this`.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems with your code:

- [avoid `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/)
- `m_value` is a `const char*`, ie a pointer to read-only memory, but you are trying to modify the data it is pointing at (via `strcpy()`), so it needs to be a `char*` instead, ie a pointer to writable memory.
- `allocateAndCopy()` doesn't account for `value` being `nullptr`.  Calling `strlen()` and `strcpy()` with a `nullptr` as input is *undefined behavior*.
- the copy constructor is not initializing `m_value` before calling `operator=`, thus making `allocateAndCopy()` call `delete[]` on an invalid pointer, which is also *undefined behavior*.
- `operator=` is declared to return a new `Name` object by value, but `this` is a `Name*` pointer. You need to return `*this` by `Name&` reference instead. You are also not accounting for the possibility of self-assignment (ie, assigning a `Name` object to itself).
- `read()` is calling `std::getline()` which requires a `std::string` not a `char[]`. And a `char[]` does not have a `c_str()` method. And you are not checking if `getline()` is even successful before passing `val` to `allocateAndCopy()`.
- `operator<<` should take in a `Name` object by `const` reference.
- your stream extraction operator is named `operator<<` (the name of the stream insertion operator). It needs to be named `operator>>` instead. Also, it needs to return `is` by reference, to allow the caller to chain multiple `>>` reads together. It is trying to return the return value of `read()`, which is `void`.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <iostream>
//#include <string>
#include <cstring>

class Name {
   char* m_value = nullptr;

   void allocateAndCopy(const char* value) {
      delete[] m_value;
      m_value = nullptr;
      if (value) {
          m_value = new char[std::strlen(value) + 1];
          std::strcpy(m_value, value);
      }
   }

public:
   Name() = default;

   Name(const char* value) {
      allocateAndCopy(value);
   }

   Name(const Name& N) {
      allocateAndCopy(N.m_value);
   }

   Name& operator=(const Name& N) {
      if (&N != this) {
          allocateAndCopy(N.m_value);
      }
      return *this;
   }

   ~Name() {
      delete[] m_value;
   }

   void display(std::ostream& os) const {
      os << m_value;
   }

   void read(std::istream& is) {
      char val[1000] = {};
      if (is.getline(val, 1000))
          allocateAndCopy(val);

      /* alternatively: 

      std::string val;
      if (std::getline(is, val))
          allocateAndCopy(val.c_str());
      */
   }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Name& N) {
   N.display(os);
   return os;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, Name& N) {
   N.read(is);
   return is;
}
```